# Python (loops) with a list

Tags: python, list, loops

I am learning Python, and struggling with conditions of a `for` loop.  I must be missing something simple. I have a list with some int values, and I want to (1) print all even numbers and (2) only print values up to a certain index. I can print the even numbers fine, but cannot seem to print only to a certain index.

```
numbers = [951, 402, 984, 651, 360, 69, 408, 319, 601, 485, 980, 507, 725, 547, 544, 615, 83, 165, 141, 501, 263, 617, 865, 575, 219, 390, 984, 592, 236, 105, 942, 941, 386, 462, 47, 418, 907, 344, 236, 375, 823, 566, 597, 978, 328, 615, 953, 345]
```

1. Prints all numbers in list -- ok:

   ```
   for i in numbers:
       print i
   ```
2. Prints all even numbers in the list -- ok:

   ```
   for i in numbers:
       if i % 2 == 0:
           print i
   ```

Let's say I want to only print even numbers up to and including the entry with the value 980 -- so that would be 402, 984, 360, 408, 980.

I have tried, unsuccessfully, to implement a count and while loop and also a conditional where I print `numbers[n] < numbers.index(980)`.

Comment: `.index(...)` is almost irrelevant imho; that is not to say that is not useful, but I have almost never needed to use it. What it does is it finds the first occurrence of a number, that is, `index(980)` would find the index of the first time the number `980` appeared in the list.

Comment: Hello , your second loop wont work because x is not defined.  You mean probably `for x in numbers: if x%2==0: print x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `break` statement which leaves current loop:

```
>>> for i in numbers:
...     if i % 2 == 0:
...         print i
...     if i == 980:
...         break
... 
402
984
360
408
980
```

Comment: @zch you should teach appropriate variable naming, too: e.g. _number_ instead of _i_ (`for number in numbers...`)

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`enumerate()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to include a loop index:

```
for i, num in enumerate(numbers):
    if num % 2 == 0 and i < 10:
        print num
```

Alternatively, just slice your list to only consider the first `n` elements, albeit that that creates a new copy of the sublist:

```
for num in numbers[:10]:
    if num % 2 == 0:
        print num
```

If you need to test for specific values of `num`, you can also exit a `for` loop early with `break`:

```
for i, num in enumerate(numbers):
    if num % 2 == 0:
        print num
    if num == 980 or i >= 10:
        break  # exits the loop early
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, let me be more precise, what if I dont know the position of the index, and I want to say only print even values up to and including the index 980 and not position [:10]?

Comment: @bburn312: Not entirely sure what you are asking. `i < 980` tests for indices up to 980, and you can add `and i != 10` to skip that index too.

Comment: @bburn312: if you however meant `num == 980`, then test for that, and just bail out with a `break`.

Comment: Minor probably-irrelevant efficiency issue: this keeps on going through the entire list without a break.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

The first uses `enumerate`, which turns `a, b, c...` into `(0,a) (1,b) (2,c) ...`

```
for i,n in enumerate(numbers):
    if i==last_index:
        break
    print n
```

The second possibility uses slices, which creates another list that represents a section of the original list:

```
for n in numbers[:last_index]:
    print n
```

This second method is not as efficient as the first since it makes a copy of the slice of the list (unless you are slicing a `range(...)` or other 'smart' object, in which case it may return a 'virtual list'). It can, however, be consider to read more cleanly, so is may be acceptable unless the section you care about is small or you don't care about memory or space efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

For manipulating lists, have a look at [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Especially with large lists, they are a lot faster than for-loops.

Based on your `numbers` list you could isolate even numbers like this:

```
In [3]: even = [n for n in numbers if n % 2 == 0]

In [4]: even
Out[4]: [402, 984, 360, 408, 980, 544, 390, 984, 592, 236, 942, 386, 462, 418, 344, 236, 566, 978, 328]
```

In which case you can just do:

```
for i in even:
    print i
```

For your second question:

```
In [7]: selection = [n for i, n in enumerate(numbers) if n % 2 == 0 and i < numbers.index(980)]

In [8]: selection
Out[8]: [402, 984, 360, 408]
```

So you can do

```
for n in selection:
    print n
```

BTW, the `In` and `Out` are from [`IPython`](http://ipython.org/), which is a great interactive Python environment.

Answer (score 0):

[itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) is a module with a lot of wonderful functions:

```
from itertools import takewhile

numbers = [951, 402, 984, 651, 360, 69, 408, 319, 601, 485, 980, 507, 725, 547, 544, 615, 83, 165, 141, 501, 263, 617, 865, 575, 219, 390, 984, 592, 236, 105, 942, 941, 386, 462, 47, 418, 907, 344, 236, 375, 823, 566, 597, 978, 328, 615, 953, 345]

for number in (number for number in takewhile(lambda x: x != 980, numbers) if number % 2 == 0):
    print(number)
```

To add more itertools functions:

```
from itertools import ifilterfalse, takewhile
for number in ifilterfalse(lambda x: x % 2, takewhile(lambda x: x != 980, numbers)):
    print(number)
```